# Android LiveData: Difference between LiveData provided as method or as variable

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-livedata-transformations

I am facing a strange, but huge difference in behaviour between observing LiveData that is exposed as a method and LiveData that is exposed as variable. Consider the following code in your ViewModel:

**LiveData as method**

```
private val carApiCall = carRepository.getCar(carId)

fun getCarColors() = Transformations.switchMap(carApiCall ) { resource ->
    when (resource.resourceStatus) {
        ResourceStatus.SUCCESS -> databaseRepository.getCarColors(carId)
    }
}
```

**LiveData as variable**

```
private val carApiCall = carRepository.getCar(carId)

val carColors = Transformations.switchMap(carApiCall ) { resource ->
    when (resource.resourceStatus) {
        ResourceStatus.SUCCESS -> databaseRepository.getCarColors(carId)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is how carColors are observable by the outside. First as as method `getCarColors()` then as a public variable `carColors`.

The car colors are observed and used by both the fragment and a few times in the xml data-binding layout.

When using the variable approach, all works fine. As soon as the API call was successful, the code requests the car colors from the database once.

When using the method approach, the API call is executed once, but the Transformation on it is called up to 20 times! Why does it behave like that?

To be clear: Both code examples end up with a working result, but for some reason the second one gets executed/called many times, although the transformed apiCall is only changed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use it as a method, the method is called separately each time you try to access it. Every time you call `getCarColors()`, it will execute the function you wrote.

When used as a variable, the code is executed only the first time - this is called variable initialization. After a variable is initialized, its value is stored in the memory, so the function you use for initialization is called only once.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that it will boil down to the method being called whenever databinding or anything else is executed. Do you know if there is a official recommendation to use one over the other? Because judging this behaviour, I see no sense anymore to expose LiveData as method (at least in Kotlin)

Comment: It really depends on the behaviour you'd like to have. Sometimes you want to always fetch new data, so a method makes more sense. But if something is static and will not change, an exposed variable is better.